# JS: async in forEach having a timing issue

Tags: javascript

I think I am having a timing issue here with how I am using async/await.  I want to loop through the `foo` array and make an api call and after those have all run, I want to `return` the last `subscribeToService` from the `forEach`.  I know it gets overridden each time but that is fine.

```
async function myFunction() {

   let foo = await makeFirstCall();

   foo.forEach(x => {
    if (!x.isEnabled) {
      const { subscribeToService } = await api.subscribeEndpoiint(
        x.id,
        x.name,
        JSON.stringify(x.name.toJSON()),
      );
    }
  });

  return subscribeToService;
}
```

Comment: From my experience, you can't rely on `forEach` when you need to `await` code inside. You should fall back to more traditional loop `for(i=0; i<x; i++)`. See => https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37576685/using-async-await-with-a-foreach-loop

Comment: forEach doesn't wait for the await aka promises, use ```for``` loop